# System Tray notifyIcon won't accept left-click event

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, click

I'm creating a System-Tray only application. It's somewhat complicated to have the icon without a main form, but through previous topics on StackOverflow I've worked it out. The right-click works fine, I've linked in a context menu, etc.

I'm having problems with the left-click. As far as I can tell, the "notifyIcon1_Click" event isn't firing at all.

```
    private void notifyIcon1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Does it work here?");

        if (e.Equals(MouseButtons.Left))
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("It worked!");
        }
    }
```

Neither of those debug lines are outputting, breakpoints in that event don't stop the program, etc.

Am I doing this incorrectly? What should my next step be? I'm coding this in C#, using Windows 7 if that matters at all for taskbar behavior.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? Is the event "wired"?

Comment: Has the event been hooked up correctly in the Designer.cs file - `this.notifyIcon1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_Click);`?

Comment: You did remember to actually register it as an event handler, right?

Comment: Thanks all :0

I get so used to it wiring them automatically for me it slips through at times like this... that and other people on the internet are having similar problems and it seemed like a larger issue.

Blah.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to determine if it's a left or right click, wire up the `MouseClick`, rather than click.

That way you get a signature like this:

```
private void notifyIcon1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        //Do the awesome left clickness
    else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        //Do the wickedy right clickness
    else
        //Some other button from the enum :)
}
```

Comment: What would be the equivalent of "this.notifyIcon1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_Click);" in this case? The obvious (that is, replacing "Click" with "MouseClick" throws a "No overload for 'notifyIcon1_MouseClick' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'" error.

Other than that, though, thanks! I was about to start on why I couldn't get left/right working, but you beat me to the punch.

Comment: *edit, trying to get the codeblocks as used by the commenter above. But it didn't work. Wish comments had a fully featured text editor...

Comment: Hey @cksubs, it would be really helpful if you could please show what you did to solve this problem so this can be helpful to future visitors like myself. ;)  Thank you!

Comment: Posted the full solution below.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the click event of the Message/Balloon itself use

```
_notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += notifyIconBalloon_Click;


private void notifyIconBalloon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
// your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void NotifyIcon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MouseEventArgs mouseEventArgs = (MouseEventArgs)e;

        if (mouseEventArgs.Button == MouseButtons.Right && IsHandleCreated)
        {
            popupMenu1.ShowPopup(MousePosition);
            return;
        }

        if (mouseEventArgs.Button == MouseButtons.Left && IsHandleCreated)
        {
            if (isWindowMinimized)
                showWindow();
            else
                hideWindow();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The other answer is not clear that you need MouseClick event instead of Click.

```
notifyIcon.MouseClick += MyClickHandler;
```

Then your handler function will work fine.

```
void MyClickHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Left click!");
    }
}
```